# Can I use a texture as hair density map?

Tags: hair

I would like to use a texture as density map because it can be much more precise than a vertex group, is it possible? In Cycles render.

Comment: You want to make it in *Cycles* or *Blender Internal*?

Answer (score 9):

In ***Cycles*** select the mesh, give it a material, then go the *Particles* header and add a new texture in the *Textures* panel.
[image]

Prepare your black and white density map. Here's mine:
[image]

Next go to the *Texture* header, add a new texture (*Image or Movie*) and check the ***Density*** checkbox in the *Influence* panel. ***Note:*** I also checked the *Lenght* checkbox to make the render look more clear.
[image]
[image]

In ***Blender Internal*** you can do it the same way. After giving the mesh a material and the particle system you go to the *Texture* header-->*Particle Texture* button, load your texture as *Image or Movie* and select what kind of influence on particles it should have.
[image]