# Removing hair particles in specific areas

Tags: particles, hair

I'm using Blender 2.78c for create a bear cub - by following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O7q2PSWmhuU).

I decide to play with the particle system in order to give the model some hair/fur, however, I'm having this issue:

- I cannot remove hair particles around their eyes, nose and mouth.

I've tried:

- In the particle edit mode, use the length brush and shrink in the areas (*i.e. eyes, nose and mouth*), also, using the comb brush.
- Remove duplicates - by clicking this option.
- Searched about this topic on other websites and here on Blender Stack Exchange.

However, despite all these efforts, in the rendered viewport shading, the hair is still present.

This is the result I have so far:

[image: Bear cub with some hair]

What I want to accomplish is to understand how to remove the hair/fur from the eyes, nose and mouth.

Here is the .blend file:

[image]

Comment: The unwanted hair comes from the *Interpolated Children* option. Blender places the new hair particles between the edited ones (=the parents). To define where you want to have the fur and where not, you can either [1) use a Vertex Group](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/292579/107598) or [2) an Image Texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/92212/107598). Both options control the hair density and should work for your model. 1) VG needs enough geometry (vertices), while the 2) IT option requires a UV map and an image. (Don't forget to remove the fur from the soles & inside of the ears)

Comment: @Blunder thank you so much. You can post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. The vertex group is the option I tested and it looks wonderful.